# SQL Query with custom field variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I need to make a SQL query where one of the variables is coming from ACF Select Field.

So far this is my code:

```
global $wpdb;
$htSQL = get_field('home_team');
$xy = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT `number` FROM `database` WHERE `team` = '" .$htSQL. "'", 0, 1)
echo $xy;
```

In this case, it seems that the SQL can't find anything since the $htSQL is the problem. 
If I echo the variable $htSQL I get the value from custom field (the value in this case is "Valencia").

I have tried the SQL query with following code and it worked

```
$xy = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT `number` FROM `database` WHERE `team` = 'Valencia'", 0, 1)
echo $xy;
```

For me it seems that the SQL don't see the the variable $htSQL as a text.
Does someone has an idea how to solve this?

Comment: mysql or SQL-Server?

Comment: Can you try to assing `"SELECT number FROM database WHERE team = '" .$htSQL. "'"` to variable and use it as first parameter?

Comment: Hi Tuğca, not sure what you mean but the query if defined as a variable which is echoed later. Check variable $xy

Answer (score 0):

In wordperss ACF plugin stores its value in wp_post_meta table so you have to query with join in post meta and post table or simply use get_post_meta function.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is it maybe possible to save the $thSQL variable as a new text variable in order to avoid complications?